# How to open url in IE using VBS if URL has %20 (space) in it

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I'm using .navigate to open a url in IE using vbs. Actually the url has 1 space " " in it and the browser accepts it only as %20.

When I'm using this

```
  .Navigate "http://abc.com?product=test%203.0"
```

It automatically converts that to space ( and become http://abc.com?product=test 3.0")  and the page do not open

Though, if you enter  "http://abc.com?product=test%203.0" manually and hit submit, It Works.

Does anyone has any idea???

Comment: .Navigate and .Navigate2 didn't make any difference here... :(

Comment: I just tried `navigate "www.stackoverflow.com?something=test%203.0"` and it seemed to work. Nothing was converted to a space